# How to export node_modules from vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

I know that vs-code is made with electron.

So I inspected vscode and in the node_modelues folder( `file:./node_modules/` )

I found `axios` as a module in it.

Its location was `file:./node_modules/axios`

How should I export the axios module in vscode and use it in my project without downloading it from npm